# Deleting a node with 2 children from a binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to delete a node having 2 chidren in a binary search tree. However i am facing little problem here. While deleting node(node with data=30) with children (left->data=20,right->data=40), I am replacing the node with its inorder successor (which is node with data=40) and then deleting the inorder successor. After deletion the node's data is successfully replaced (new value being 40) but the inorder successor is not being deleted/freed properly.

Expected Output [inorder traversal]: 20->40->50->60->70->80->

Output[inorder traversal]: 20->40->0->50->60->70->80->

After 40, why is the value 0 appearing?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node
{ 
    int data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

struct Node* temp = NULL,*temp1 = NULL;
struct Node *newNode(int data)
{
    struct Node *node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->data = data;
    node->left = node->right = NULL;

    return node;
}

struct Node* insert(struct Node* root,int data)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        return newNode(data);
    }

    if(data < root->data)
        root->left = insert(root->left,data);
    else
        root->right = insert(root->right,data);
}

void inorder(struct Node* root)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        inorder(root->left);    
        printf("%d->",root->data); 
        inorder(root->right);    
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
 /*to find the inorder successor*/
struct Node *minVal(struct Node *root)
{
    while(root->left !=NULL)
    {
        temp = root;
        root = root->left;
    }

    return root;
}

void deleteNode(struct Node *root,int data)
{
    if(data < root->data)
    {
        temp = root; 
        deleteNode(root->left,data);  
    }
    else if(data > root->data)
    {
        temp = root;
        deleteNode(root->right,data);
    }
    else if(data == root->data)
    { /*deleting leaf nodes*/
        if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
        {
            if(temp->left == root)
                temp->left = NULL;
            else
                if(temp->right == root)
            temp->right = NULL;
            free(root);
            root = NULL;
            return;
        }
         /*deleting nodes having single child*/
        else if(root->left !=NULL && root->right == NULL)
        {
            temp1 = root->left;
            temp->left = temp1;
            free(root);
            root = NULL;
        }
        else if(root->left ==NULL && root->right != NULL)
        {
            temp1 = root->right;
            temp->right = temp1;
            free(root);
            root = NULL;
        }
         /*deleting nodes having 2 children*/
        else if(root->left !=NULL && root->right !=NULL)
        {
            struct Node *temp2 = minVal(root->right);
            root->data = temp2->data;
            deleteNode(root->right,temp2->data);
        }  
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *root = NULL;
    printf("\n\n");

    root = insert(root, 50);
    insert(root, 30);
    insert(root, 20);
    insert(root, 40);
    insert(root, 70);
    insert(root, 60);
    insert(root, 80);

    inorder(root);
    //deleteNode(root,40);
    deleteNode(root,30);
    printf("\n\n");
    inorder(root);

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you show sample input?

Comment: What is the meaning of `temp = root;` in all your functions? Having shared temporary fields aptly named `temp` and `temp1` is a road to failure. Have you heard of [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Comment: Do you know there is something called MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @potato the OP's code compiles.

Comment: You are leaking memory when you simply do `temp->left = NULL`. Do not use global variables in recursive functions, it just defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Groo temp = root, so that I can store the value of the parent in temp for later use. Lose of memory will definitely happen but then i was just experimenting with global variables.

Comment: @oldDoctor: Using global variables should be avoided in programming. They should never be used for temporary variables. And when writing recursive functions, state is passed through function parameters, not by writing it to some global location.